# What exactly is @from-width & @from-table in CSS code

Tags: css, styled-jsx

I am trying to read some code and I see the below 'annotations' inside styled jsx:

```css
@from-width tablet {
  h1 {
    font-size: ${`calc(${theme.font.size.xxxl} * 1.2)`};
  }
}
```

```css
@from-width desktop {
  h1 {
    font-size: ${`calc(${theme.font.size.xxxl} * 1.4)`};
  }
}
```

```css
@below desktop {
  ul {
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
}
```

I am curious to know what the `@from-width`, `@below` terms used here called. And what is their purpose.

While I do understand that these blocks define the css for different screen sizes, but I couldn't find any syntax information on the net.

I also tried to search on google but couldn't find any mention. I also searched in the repository and didn't find any sort of 'declaration/definition' of these terms as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is the library https://github.com/gsantiago/postcss-easy-media-query

```
@from-width 768px {}
/* @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {} */

@below 400px {}
/* @media screen and (max-width: 399px) {} */
```